# Airflow: psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: Value too long for character type

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I have a SUBDAG that fails and it gives me the following error, and I want to make sure which is the value too long that it's been inserted on the table and maybe with the location I can figure out which is the value that it's being to long.

The code is the following:

```
[2022-08-17 05:19:33,251] {postgres_operator.py:62} INFO - Executing: insert into user_visit ( 
        select ew.uri                                                       uri
            , date_trunc('day',ew.created_at)                               created_at
            , ew.platform                                                   platform
            , ew."type"                                                     "type"
            , count(uuid)                                                  traffic
            , ew."host"                                                     "host"
             from event_web ew  where date_trunc('day',ew.created_at) >       date_trunc('day',coalesce((select max(created_at) from user_visit ),'1000-01-01')) group by uri,created_at,platform,"type","host"); 
[2022-08-17 05:19:33,262] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2022-08-17 05:19:33,262] {base_hook.py:84} INFO - Using connection to: id: dwh_redshift. Host: dwh-pro.cefs12046ciy.eu-central-1.redshift.amazonaws.com, Port: 5439, Schema: pro, Login: etl_user, Password: XXXXXXXX, extra: None
[2022-08-17 05:19:33,383] {logging_mixin.py:112} INFO - [2022-08-17 05:19:33,383] {dbapi_hook.py:174} INFO - insert into user_visit ( 
        select ew.uri                                                       uri
            , date_trunc('day',ew.created_at)                               created_at
            , ew.platform                                                   platform
            , ew."type"                                                     "type"
            , count(uuid)                                                  traffic
            , ew."host"                                                     "host"
             from event_web ew  where date_trunc('day',ew.created_at) >       date_trunc('day',coalesce((select max(created_at) from user_visit ),'1000-01-01')) group by uri,created_at,platform,"type","host");
```

And the message error is this one:

```
psycopg2.errors.InternalError_: Value too long for character type
    DETAIL:  
      -----------------------------------------------
      error:  Value too long for character type
      code:      8001
      context:   Value too long for type character varying(2048)
      query:     67463367
      location:  string.cpp:247
      process:   query1_221_67463367 [pid=31276]
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to airflow. When you insert your data to the table `user_visit`, there is a column in this table of type `varchar(2048)` which doesn't accept a string with more than 2048 characters, but in your data you are trying to insert, there is a record which has a value of this column with size > 2048. You can check your data to know what is the max size you can have, then update the table by increasing the column varchar size.

Comment: Hello! Yes I realised about that, I've increased the length and it still not works... Thank you anyway!